# Polyomino group structure?

Tags: group-theory, geometry

Has anyone ever heard of (can you think of) of a group structure on $\mathbb{P}$, the set of all polyominoes?  Ideally the monomino would be our identity element, I'd say.  (Thanks to Justin Lanier for the great question.)

$\mathbb{P}$ is countable, so of course we can jam the structure of the integers or rationals on top of it, or any countable group for that matter.  I want something that relates to the geometric properties of the polyominoes.

I've built operations that have inverses for every element but are not associative or well-defined.  I'd love to hear that there's something out there that I just can't find, but I'd also love to hear your thoughts on the problem.
Thanks!

Comment: What is a polyomino?

Comment: @metina an edge-connected set of edge-aligned squares with equivalence defined by geometrical transformations. Or do you have some other definition in mind that is useful here?

Comment: one square = monomino; two squares = domino; ... ; five squares = pentomino; ... . There are twelve double-sided (invariant under mirror reversal) pentominoes (with a standard set of letter mnemonics).

Comment: That looks good, @JanDvorak.  If it's useful for the problem, we could drop the rotations and call those distinct.  It's also common to disallow reflections.

Comment: @paul that's not the standard procedure for polyominoes but you are free to discuss the case - it could yield some interesting results.

Comment: @JanDvorak - What is not the standard procedure?  By disallowing reflections I mean to say that they are two distinct L tetrominoes.  (And distinct S tetrominoes for that matter.)

Obviously we're free to define "pollyominoes" if we so choose, with whatever stipulations we find useful.  :)

Comment: I like the idea of this problem, but I'm not sure how to come up with an operation. I'll think about it.